Laravel query to get sum of multiple relationship counts using e.g. union in relationship or selectRaw
I have a Laravel 11 setup with Timeline and Place models.
Timeline has a timestamp and a place_id. A place can have child places, using parent_id to point to the parent place.
Question: how do I (eager) query the places to include the sum of the timeline visits to the main place and child places?
I have two Place relationships for the (direct) visits and visits to the child places, so: no problem to get them separately.
E.g.
Place::query()
  ->withCount('visits') // visits_count, e.g. 118
  ->withCount('visitsChildren') // visits_children_count, e.g. 481

Following this answer and this answer, I tried:
// app/Models/Place

public function visitsTotal()
{
    // only getting specific fields to avoid the SQL error: 
    // The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

    return $this->visits()->select('timelines.id')
        ->union($this->visitsChildren()->select('timelines.id'));
}

This works for a specific place:
Place::find($placeId)->visits->count(); // 118
Place::find($placeId)->visitsChildren->count(); // 481
Place::find($placeId)->visitsTotal->count(); // 599 (=118+481)


But it does not work for an eager query:
Place::query()
  ->where('id', $placeId)
  // ->withCount('visits') // 118
  // ->withCount('visitsChildren') // 481
  ->withCount('visitsTotal') // expected: 599, but I get: 118
  ->get()

So, then I get for visits_total_count the same number as for the main visits (e.g. 118).
I also tried to add a select:
Place::query()
  ->where('id', $placeId)
  ->withCount('visits') // visits_count, e.g. 118
  ->withCount('visitsChildren') // visits_children_count, e.g. 481
  ->selectRaw('visits_count + visits_children_count as visits_total_count') // expected: 599
  ->get()

But then I get an error: Unknown column 'visits_count' in 'field list'.
The relationships:
// app/Models/Place

public function visits()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Timeline::class);
}

public function visitsChildren()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        Timeline::class, // the end result
        Place::class, // going through this one
        'parent_id', // foreign key on going through Place (child)
        'place_id', // foreign key on Timeline
        'id', // local key on Place (parent)
        'id' // local key on going through Place (child)
    );
}

The toRawSql() query that's created when trying selectRaw:
SELECT
    `places`.*,
    (
        SELECT
            count(*)
        FROM
            `timelines`
        WHERE
            `places`.`id` = `timelines`.`place_id`) AS `visits_count`, 
    (
        SELECT
            count(*)
        FROM
            `timelines`
            INNER JOIN `places` AS `laravel_reserved_2` ON `laravel_reserved_2`.`id` = `timelines`.`place_id`
        WHERE
            `laravel_reserved_2`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
            AND `places`.`id` = `laravel_reserved_2`.`parent_id`) AS `visits_children_count`, 
    visits_count + visits_children_count AS visits_total_count
    FROM
        `places`


Is there anything that stops you from simply using both available aggregated counts when you need to show the data? Total: {{ $place->visits_count + $place->visits_children_count }}

Good point, I want to e.g. order them by the total visits, so as part of the query. As opposed to: calculate the total afterwards.

Given the relationships (HasMany ans HasManyThrough) both point to the same model, there is perhaps a hack you could use. Try defining another relationship based on visitsChildren and adding an extra condition to it.
public function visitsTotal(): HasManyThrough
{
    return $this->visitsChildren()->orWhereColumn('timelines.place_id', 'places.id');
}

Alternatively, I'd suggest just using the two available counts and if sorting is really important, it can still be done through Collection methods

The workaround works, thanks! Suggestions on why union(...) would not work?

At first glance, I'd say the issue with your union(...) solution was passing a relationship object ($this->visitsChildren()->select('timelines.id') is a HasManyThrough object) so the behavior was probably weird.
